# How to create a DROWN attack

Tags: attacks, vulnerability

I need to create a test lab to demonstrate how a DROWN (
Decrypting RSA with Obsolete and Weakened eNcryption) attack can be preformed, does anyone know of a guide or steps in how to create this attack?

I need to demonstrate this for my honors but I can not find anything on this. I know how to test if a server is vulnerable, how to resolve the issue but I can not find anything on how to actually preform the attack.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You cannot find anything? The orginial paper describing the attack is prominent in searches https://drownattack.com/drown-attack-paper.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Like the first comment said, i find it very doubtful you can't find anything.

A complete description of the implementation can be found here:
https://drownattack.com/drown-attack-original-report.pdf

I think what you mean is; "Can you point me to a public PoC i can copy."

No.

This attack is highly dangerous. And while it is an awesome school project, it can be used to defraud banks and steal highly sensitive information so it makes sense to restrict the tools to do that.

If you want to construct the attack yourself, look into the Bleichenbacher padding oracle side-channel attack.

[Here you can find an implementation of this.](https://github.com/duesee/bleichenbacher)

Furthermore the whitepaper mentions this to increase the likelyhood of finding a valid padding:

> Efficient padding oracle attacks on cryptographic hardware. In
>   Advances in Cryptology–CRYPTO
>   2012. Springer, 2012, pp. 608–625.

Then, to use an SSLv2 server as an oracle to show the validity of the padding:

> This allows an attacker to deduce the validity of RSA
>   ciphertexts in the following manner:
>   1.
>   The   attacker   sends   a
>   ClientMasterKey
>   mes-
>   sage,  which  contains  an  RSA  ciphertext
>   c
>   0
>   and
>   any  sequence  of  11  bytes  as  the  clear  portion
>   of   the
>   master_key
>   ,
>   mk
>   clear
>   .
>   The   server   re-
>   sponds  with  a
>   ServerVerify
>   message,   which
>   contains   the
>   challenge
>   encrypted   using   the
>   server_write_key
>   .
>   2.
>   The  attacker  performs  an
>   exhaustive  search
>   over
>   the   possible   values   of   the   5   bytes   of   the
>   master_key
>   mk
>   secret
>   .
>   He  then  computes  the
>   corresponding
>   server_write_key
>   and   checks
>   whether the
>   ServerVerify
>   message decrypts to the
>   challenge
>   .  One value should pass this check; let
>   this value be termed
>   mk
>   0
>   .  Recall that if the RSA
>   plaintext was valid,
>   mk
>   0
>   is the unpadded data in the
>   RSA plaintext. Otherwise,
>   mk
>   0
>   is a randomly gener-
>   ated sequence of 5 bytes.
>   3.
>   The  attacker  re-connects  to  the  server  with  the
>   same  RSA  ciphertext
>   c
>   0
>   .
>   The  server  responds
>   with another
>   ServerVerify
>   message that contains
>   the current
>   challenge
>   encrypted using the current
>   server_write_key
>   . If the decrypted RSA cipher-
>   text was valid, the attacker can directly decrypt a
>   correct
>   challenge
>   value from the
>   ServerVerify
>   message by using the
>   master_key
>   mk
>   0
>   . Otherwise,
>   if the
>   ServerVerify
>   message does not correctly
>   decrypt to the
>   challenge
>   , the RSA ciphertext was
>   invalid, and the attacker knows the
>   mk
>   0
>   value was
>   generated at random.